# Vim SQL omnicomplete

Tags: vim, omnicomplete, vim-plugin

I'm trying to use the dynamic SQL auto completion (omni menu) feature in vim, but it's not working.

I'm using the Yakuake terminal on Linux Mint, and the [DBext vim plugin](https://github.com/vim-scripts/dbext.vim) is working.

I can do <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-o</kbd>, but it only shows tables and I need columns too. I also can't drill with left and right.

If I’m in insert mode and I press <kbd>C-c</kbd> then it acts like I pressed <kbd>Esc</kbd> and goes back to normal mode.

When I type `:SQLSetType pgsql` it says "not an editor command".

Comment: this seems to be duplicated on superuser.   I'm having the same problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i added

```
filetype plugin on
```

in my .vimrc file
and the the hotkey is crtl+shift+c (like if you want to copy from terminal)
after you press that combination you press t to show all the tables and then left to drill down to the columns of the highlighted table,

the rest is in

```
:h sql.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

For whoever lands here: I've created a sql plugin for VIM, which also has intellisense: https://github.com/cosminadrianpopescu/vim-sql-workbench. It is based on SQL Workbench.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so the [ft_sql](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/ft_sql.html#sql-completion-columns) documentation seems to say that the shortcut to get to columns isn't <kbd>C-c</kbd>, but in fact <kbd>C-C c</kbd> which could either mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> and then hit <kbd>c</kbd> or  it could mean <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>LCtrl</kbd>-<kbd>c</kbd>.

Unfortunately, it's more than a little strange, so keep trying combinations and see if you can find what works!